# After some time all programs from different workspaces end up on the first workspace. GNOME 42.0 version

Tags: 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and I use workspaces extensively to host programs across different workspaces. But I ran into a problem - after a while, all programs from different workspaces end up on the first workspace and they again need to be distributed to different workspaces. Have I missed a setting somewhere to prevent this from happening, or is it a system bug that programs from all workspaces are reset to the main one?

P.S. This was also observed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Update:  Under Settings > Multitasking I have default "Dynamic workspaces"

Update 2: Under Settings > Multitasking changed to "Fixed number of workspaces" with value 4.
Bug repeated.

Comment: Under `Settings` > `Multitasking` have you set `Fixed number of workspaces` (and the number required) as opposed to the default `Dynamic workspaces`? Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: This is a gnome bug and should be reported to gnome.https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues

Comment: Created issue
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5413

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, configuring the workspaces to "Fixed number of workspaces" and "Workspaces on primary display only" resolved this issue for me. (`Settings` > `Multitasking` > `Workspaces` | `Multi-monitor`)

[image: Screenshot of settings applied]

There seem to be a couple of issues raised for this in the GNOME project: [#5413](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5413) [#2086](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2086) [#1046](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1046)

So hopefully this gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I left the "Dynamic number of workspaces", and made "Workspaces on primary display only".

Now windows don't move to the first workspace.
I guess it's a crutch, but for me it works.